# reports - user design reports - how to build a very complex dynamic query

Tags: php, mysql, report

I have a HR SaaS built on PHP.

We have a lot of objects (company, clients, apliances, proposal, etc... like a mini ERP).

The way we do the reports today is... each one is a method, with a fixed query, fixed cols and etc.

I want to build a report class, where the user can choose which cols from which object to build their own reports (like vtigercrm, sugarcrm).

My real difficult is to build the query, with joins, selects, groups and etc.

Any advice to a good database model to structure the report?

ps: sorry for the bad english.

Tkz
Roberto

Comment: is it an API? or do you have SQL accessibility to the database directly? what is the relational model?

Comment: Hi... i have SQL directly. The DB have more than 150 tables. For reports ill use a lot of them. Try to second to third form model.

Comment: you have a couple choices - build VIEWS with all the display columns - then let the usrs supply matching values and display the results - or dynamically construct SQl  the SQL option is very difficult, and comes to a design that converts something the user can speak or write in natural language into SQL - or somewhere inbetween :)